# Different Boot behavior for cloned Pi

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-3b+

I am running a python script on my Pi 3 B+ and registered it in a crontab @reboot so it is executed when booting the system. On my development Pi everything works fine, but when I clone the SD-Card and boot another Pi it takes up to 5 minutes until the python script is executed (thismeans an increase by factor 10). So I wonder if there is any known issue that may cause this behavior. I am running Raspbian Stretch (latest version).

Comment: How have you catered for network addresses being the same?

Comment: @joan: The tested Pis are behaving like this without being connected to any network.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian is using **systemd** as init system and to manage services and to emulate old style daemons from the deprecated **SysV** init system. For compatibility issues look at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). **crontab** is such an emulated system in particular its `@reboot` function. systemd uses its own `*.timer` services and **Unit** files to start services.

In `man 5 crontab` you can find:

> Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is the time when the cron(8) daemon startup.  In particular, it may  be before some system daemons, or other facilities, were startup.  This is due to the boot order sequence of the machine.

This is the reason why your script starts later on the productive installation: it does not have the same boot order of its services. And no, you can't define a boot order. On **systemd** with its parallel execution of starting services a boot order doesn't make sense. You have to define dependencies.

You should use a regular **Unit** file to start your python script. You will find many examples here on this site how to do it.

Comment: I don't follow.  Surely a cloned card has the same software.  Why should the boot sequence be different?

Comment: @joan Its running on a different hardware. Anyway, its always a good idea not to use deprecated functions in particular if you have problems.

Comment: The OP doesn't say there are any hardware differences.

Comment: @joan Quote: "*..and boot another Pi it takes up to 5 minutes until the python script is executed*".

Comment: Yes, I understand it is a different physical Pi.  I just disagree that the boot sequence will have any relevance in these circumstances.  The OP has made no mention of any difference in the hardware.

Comment: @joan I'm pretty sure that the script needs dependent services but with cron it does not check any dependencies. With SysV it may work because the boot sequence is determined but with systemd it is not. It may differ on a cold and a hot RasPi. You can speculate that a boot sequence must be the same but it is not allowed to base software on it because it isn't defined. In contrast the documentation says that you should not count on that.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try a Unit file on Monday and will report if this solves the issue. Thank you for helping me.